# How to exclude node_modules from Vitest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vite, vitest

I am trying to execute a unit test in Vitest. I've set up my application in Vue, Vite, and Vitest.

When I run my test I get the following error message:

```
Cannot use import statement outside a module
import { getSession } from 'access';
^^^^^^
```

I checked and I think it has something to do with excluding node_modules, but that should be excluded by default.

I added the exclude explicitly now, but I'm still getting the same error. Below is my vite.config.ts.

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    test: {
        environment: 'happy-dom',
        globals: true,
        mockReset: true,
        restoreMocks: true,
        clearMocks: true,
        exclude: [
            ...configDefaults.exclude,
            '<rootDir>/node_modules/**'
        ]
    },
})
```

Does anyone know how I might fix this?

Comment: Why does the error seem node_modules related? like you said, vitest already excludes node_modules by default... the error is likely not related.  Is this import statement something you've written?  Can you explain what it's for and where it is?

Comment: @yoduh, yes ofcourse. One of the packages I'm importing in the component I'm testing for is using that specific package. One thing I'm noticing is, is that that package is not built. It doesn't have a dist folder. Could that be the issue?

Comment: The question is wrong. It's not about it being excluded, it's about to process it correctly. In your case it's either transformIgnorePatterns or to mock the module. Likely the latter because you are supposed to mock every unit except the unit that you test.